# Why React updates this part of the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say that I have this [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) component:

```
var React= require("react");

var LikeButton= React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {liked: false};
    },

    handleClick: function(event){
        this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked});
    },

    render: function(){
        var text = this.state.liked ? 'like' : 'haven\'t liked';
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{new Date().toTimeString()}</h1>    
                <p onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    You {text} this. click to toggle.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<LikeButton/>, document.getElementById('mount'));
```

When I fire an `onClick` event, the `h1` element get updated with the current date, Why?

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. You change the state of a component, the component re-renders?

Comment: The *whole* component will re-render, not some parts of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a component's state is changed, its `render` method will fire.

From the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional
>   rendering  logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable
>   objects are  being used and the logic cannot be implemented in
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state
>   differs from the previous state  will avoid unnecessary re-renders.